# Api-Platform: Eager Loading a Subresource

Tags: php, rest, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

Hello guys I just started using Api-Platform and I got stuck on this problem for several hours.

I have a Symfony4 Project and two Entities: `Bill` & `Abo`

**Bill:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BillRepository")
 * @ApiResource
 */
class Bill {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Abo", inversedBy="bills")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn
     * @ApiSubresource
     */
    private $abo;
}
```

**Abo:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AboRepository")
 * @ApiResource
 */
class Abo
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Bill", mappedBy="abo")
     */
    private $bills;
}
```

When I now call this url, `/api/bills`, I get get back this data:

```
{
  "@id": "/api/bills/14",
  "@type": "Bill",
  "id": 14,
  "date": "2018-03-08T00:00:00+00:00",
  "abo": "/api/abos/1"
},
...
```

But instead of this `"abo": "/api/abos/1"` I want the Abo data already loaded, something like this:

```
"abo": {
    "name": "TestAbo",
    "price": 25
}
```

Is this possible and if yes how can I achieve this?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use serialization groups for this. Make sure that your relation field `$abo` and it's member fields groups are exposed.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BillRepository")
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *   "normalization_context"={"groups"={"bill", "bill-abo", "abo"}}
 * })
 */
class Bill {

  ...

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Abo", inversedBy="bills")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn
   * @ApiSubresource
   * @Groups("bill-abo")
   */
   private $abo;

   ...

}

class Abo {

    ...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     * @Groups("abo")
     */
    private $name;

    ...
}
```

You can read more in the [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations).

Comment: I got another question, is it possible to use `/api/bills` to show all bills without the abo and something like `/api/bills?abo` to load the bills and the abo?

Comment: @Dario I've never tried it, but I think this is what you are looking for: [filter by group](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#serializer-filters) or [fitler by proprety](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters/#property-filter)

Comment: You can use ExistsFilter fo this case https://api-platform.com/docs/core/filters#exists-filter

Comment: Is it possible to load relations without the use of Groups? Otherwise I'll have to add a lot of groups and for every property that I want to include in the request which seems inefficient.